# I'm getting error on winform application on windows 10

Tags: vb.net

I get this error when using windows 10.

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast COM object of type
>   'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Shell32.Shell'. This operation
>   failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the
>   interface with IID '{34936BA1-67AD-4C41-99B8-8C12DFF1E974}' failed due
>   to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

my code:

```
Dim shell As New Shell32.Shell
Dim objFolder As Shell32.Folder
Dim objItem As Shell32.FolderItem
Dim propertyValue As String = Nothing
Dim propertyName As String = Nothing

objFolder = shell.NameSpace("myFilepath")
objItem = objFolder.ParseName("file.xlsx")
```

Works fine on windows 7. Is there anyway to make it work on windows 7 and windows 10?

Comment: Probably applies: [Instantiate Shell32.Shell object in Windows 8](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b25e2b8f-141a-4a1c-a73c-1cb92f953b2b/instantiate-shell32shell-object-in-windows-8?forum=clr)

Comment: what's even more weird, I publish my application using clickonce. When i install it on windows 10 machine, i get the error above. If i open the project on windows 10, i don't get the error on the windows 10  machine, but if i publish it from windows 10 and install it on windows 7 i get the error.

Comment: @Plutonix tried that, it doesn't work.